# How I can show a notification in jsp that your session is about to timeout

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, security

I need to show a notification on my web app that your session is about to timeout rather than redirect to the login page.

Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
  protected boolean onAccessDenied(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    
    if (isLoginRequest(request, response)) {
        if (isLoginSubmission(request, response)) {
            return executeLogin(request, response);
        } else {
            //allow them to see the login page ;)
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        Cookie[] cookies = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getCookies();
        if (cookies != null && cookies.length > 0) {
          Cookie cookie = null;
          for (Cookie aroCookie: cookies) {
            if (xxxCookie.getName().equals("xxxCookie")) {
              cookie = xxxCookie;
              break;
            }
          }
          if (cookie != null) {            
            //userSessionStatus
          }
        }
        //redirect to login page if session timeout
        saveRequestAndRedirectToLogin(request, response);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case, I don't think the attached code is related to this question? As that would be called once access is denied.

Comment: Actually, I want a popup just to inform the user that your session is going to expire in just a few minutes.